# Storing df in variable not working

Tags: linux, bash

Here's the contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISKREPORT="$(df -hl | grep -vE 'boot|shm' | column -t)"

mail -s "$HOSTNAME Disk Usage Report: $diskreport" myemail@mydomain.com
```

What's happening is the script hangs when I call it, as if waiting for something else to happen.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  This is what I ended up with, thanks to your help:

```
#!/bin/bash
  #set -x
  DISKREPORT=$(df -hl | grep -vE 'boot|shm' | column -t | cut -f5 --complement)

  mail -s "$HOSTNAME Disk Usage Report" jsc-dl-agdl-admin@mail.nasa.gov << EOF
  $DISKREPORT
  EOF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'mail' command is waiting for stdin for the mail body (see [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_Mail.htm) for more details). You can feed a body in using a [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) e.g.

```
$ mail -s "My subject" <<EOF
My
mail
body
here
EOF
```

Note also that `DISKREPORT` is defined in capitals, but you're referencing it later using lowercase, which in bash's world is a different variable!

Comment: This is what I ended up with, thanks to your help:
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
DISKREPORT=$(df -hl | grep -vE 'boot|shm' | column -t | cut -f5 --complement)

mail -s "$HOSTNAME Disk Usage Report" jsc-dl-agdl-admin@mail.nasa.gov << EOF
$DISKREPORT
EOF

Comment: Convoluted, but it works. My solution was better. [stamps foot]  Just joking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an undefined variable `$diskreport` in your code (*and*, as another user pointed out, `mail` will be waiting for input), but apart from that, would you not much rather have the report in the *body* of the message?

```
df -hl | grep -vE 'boot|shm' | column -t | mail -s report myemail@mydomain.com
```